# How to automatically post to facebook wall?

Tags: facebook, meteor, facebook-javascript-sdk, meteor-accounts

I am creating a meteor blog and I want to make my blog post automatically posted to my Facebook wall. Moreover i will make this blog a multi user blog so any user who posts on this blog, their post will also be posted to their respective Facebook wall. I don't need specific meteor way of doing this but i would like to know how this can be achieved in general. If there are multiple ways, please tell me that too.

Answer (score 1):

Todos

- User needs to login to facebook or any such services from your app.
- Your app requires approval(permissions) to post on user's behalf.
- You expect your app to be database driven.

There is a meteor way to achieve these workflow. [Refer this doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithexternalservice) which showcase meteor's in-built service,

```
Meteor.loginWith<ExternalService>([options], [callback])
```

All necessary data like access token, email will be saved in server i.e. mongodb database.

Once user successfully logged in, you can publish post from your client. You may like to go through this [javascript quickstart](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.3) for Facebook SDK Graph API.